# K-tree and Partial k-tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have some confusion in understanding the definitions of $k$-tree and partial $k$-tree. I have refereed to wikipedia for these definitions but they are not clear for me. Can somebody explain these two definitions with some examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a quite straight-forward definition for this:

> Every $k$-tree may be formed by starting with a $(k + 1)$-vertex complete graph and then repeatedly adding vertices in such a way that each added vertex has exactly $k$ neighbors that form a clique.

The *partial $k$-trees* are graphs that are subgraphs (not necessarily induced) of $k$-trees.  They happen to form the class of bounded treewidth graphs.